# which method to use t-test or regression?

Tags: regression, t-test

Let's say There are 3 columns of data (A, B, C):

t-test of the means for A & B: Insignificant difference
t-test of the means for A & C: Significant difference

R-squared for A~B: 0.4
R-squared for A~C: 0.7

The question to be answered is the elements of which two columns (A&B or A&C) are closer to each other i.e. A[i]==B[i].

Which method is more informative here? Or should another method be implemented?

Comment: The differences between the means answer that. Plot the data to compare the distributions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're apparently looking for whether $A_i \approx B_i$ or $A_i \approx C_i$ is more true, neither of the approaches you've taken is really appropriate:

- The $t$-test of means only tells you if the mean values are close, even if individual pairs are far apart.
- The Pearson correlation coefficient does line up the sequences, but allows arbitrary linear relationships, so the actual values could be far apart.

First off, you should plot the data; perhaps a scatterplot of $A$ versus $B$ and another of $A$ versus $C$. Depending on your purposes, this may be all you need to answer your question.

If you're intent on something more quantitative, one reasonable approach might be: construct sequences $X_i = \lvert A_i - B_i \rvert$ and $Y_i = \lvert A_i - C_i \rvert$. Now, do a test for whether the population means differ, perhaps a [signed rank test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) or [paired t test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Dependent_t-test_for_paired_samples). You want these absolute deviations to be small. (You may instead want squared deviations to be small, or some other measure of distance; it depends on what you're looking for....)